# design error with viewpager

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to fix this problem but it does not work I searched a lot and did not find problems like this , this picture
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnyKu.png)
see the red line How to go abroad
xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_home" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
                app:tabTextColor="#64ffffff">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Categories" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="NEW POSTS" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Stats" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#beffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_cover_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/cover_header" />


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">




        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:text="My World"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>



            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/share_icon"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"/>








    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

everything works fine but does not show all the content

I'm sorry but my language is bad, I hope to get some help to solve this problem , thanks a lot and best regards

Comment: Please post text not pictures of your code

Comment: I've posted the text

Comment: I think android:fitsSystemWindows="true" cause this.Make it false and try again what you got?

Comment: You can see the picture does not appear complete :( , https://imgur.com/a/601IJ

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your LinearLayout to take up no more screen, try remove this line 
`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from LinearLayout

Comment: Didn`t you try to use ScrollView? It seems, you need to use ScrollView if you have some limited numder items, or you need RecyclerView